# Reference for combinatorics with view towards representation theory/algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, geometric-representation-theory

I'm making this post to ask for a reference about combinatorics: I'm a PhD student in representation theory/algebraic geometry. My background is mostly in algebra and geometry (and also mostly theoretical unfortunately).

Right now I'm interested in the cohomology of quiver and character varieties and their links with cohomological Hall algebras, quantum groups and the character ring of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{F}_q)$. There's a lot of interesting combinatorics going on, but I really know very little about it. Especially regarding MacDonald polynomials etc.

Outside of the classic book by Macdonald "Symmetric functions and Hall polynomials" what could be a good reference to get into this area of combinatorics? Ideally I would like a book or notes with strong link to representation theory/cohomology theories etc

Comment: On the very combinatorial side (so not really satisfying your request to have strong links to representation theory, etc.) is Jim Haglund's book on $q$,$t$-Catalan numbers: https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~jhaglund/books/qtcat.pdf.

Comment: Why 'unfortunately' in "mostly theoretical unfortunately"?

Comment: Combinatorics of Coxeter groups https://www.google.com/books/edition/Combinatorics_of_Coxeter_Groups/1TBPz5sd8m0C?hl=en

Comment: Possibly of interest is F. Bergeron, *Algebraic Combinatorics and Coinvariant Spaces*. See http://bergeron.math.uqam.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/book_debut.pdf.

Comment: *Crystal Bases: Representations and Combinatorics* by Bump and Schilling may be relevant to your interests. They don't focus on cohomology per se, but they do give a very nice combinatorial development of (some of) the representation theory that you allude to.

Comment: @Lspice I kinda feel that purely theoric mathematical formation at least in my case did not give enough importance to concrete examples and computations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

M. Haiman "Notes on Macdonald polynomials and the geometry of the Hilbert scheme of points on $\mathbb{P}^2$". By one of the greatest specialists of interactions between combinatorics and algebraic geometry.

Comment: See https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/ftp/newt-sf-2001/newt.pdf and also http://library.msri.org/books/Book38/files/haiman.pdf

Answer (score 10):

I am not that strong on the representation-theory side, but know more about the combinatorics side. If you want to get an overview of the symmetric functions and the associated combinatorics (crystal bases, RSK etc), then one starting point (with references!) is [www.symmetricfunctions.com](https://www.symmetricfunctions.com).

I am the admin for this site, so all errors and issues are completely my fault :)